# Where I can find the log files of thin webserver

Tags: web-server, log-files, thin, sinatra

I'm using thin web server for my sinatra application. Some times it generate 504 gateway time out.

Where I can see the access and error logs of thin?

Answer (score 3):

Thin logging is rather sparse and not very flexible compared to usual suspects like Apache / Nginx.

You could enable debug level logging in the standard log file by passing `--debug` option in the command line during Thin's execution, or adding `debug: yes` option to Thin's application configuration .yml file.

For more gory details, you can also add `--trace` / `trace: yes` option. This will display almost **everything** that is passing through Thin, including request and response contents.

There's also a `--stats PATH` / `stats: PATH` option that allows you to activate a special statistics web page at the specified PATH (e.g. `/thin-stats`), which shows number of requests processed by Thin and some various header data.

Run `thin -h` to view all command line options, which could be passed to thin.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `thin -h`. By the default, it located at `log/thin.log`.

Comment: log/thin.log does not have access and error logs. It logs only the things we give in the program.
Is there any access/error log file like apache2 and nginx has?